# JPA - deleteBy query not working, orphanRemoval=true not working

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am unable to understand why `JPA delete` is not working. Here is my parent entity:

```
public class RoleEntity {

 //...other attributes like name etc.

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<RoleExtEntity> extensions;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private FileEntity fileEntity;
}
```

`RoleRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, Long> {
   @Transactional
   int deleteByFileEntityAndName(FileEntity fileEntity, String roleName);
}
```

I am trying to delete the `RoleEntity` using `FileEntity` and `RoleName` attributes. The `delete` query returns `val = 1` however when I do a `findBy` again, it gives me the record instead of `null` (as I think the record should be deleted, both parent and child should be deleted).

```
FileEntity fileEntity = fileRepository.findByFolderId(id); 
RoleEntity roleToBeDeleted = roleRepository.findByFileEntityAndName(fileEntity, roleName);
int val = roleRepository.deleteByFileEntityAndName(fileEntity, roleName);
RoleEntity doesroleExistEntity = roleRepository.findByFileEntityAndName(fileEntity, roleName);
```

I have tried out various solutions mentioned on this platform like by using:

- `orphanRemoval = true`
- `@Transactional` annotation
- `flush()`
- `CascadeType.ALL`

However, they don't seem to work. Can someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly here? Thanks!

**Update:** The issue was that I was calling a wrong method from a persistence service in my code. That method was a `readOnlyTransaction()` which didn't allow me to do the delete so I had to use another method `withTransaction()` that solved my issue.

Comment: It is still in the 1st level cache, you are getting the cached instance. Nothing is deleted until the transaction commits, assuming this is called from a service method that itself is transactional. Also the `deleteByFileEntityAndName` will actually just create a `delete` query it will *not** use the metadata to delete the remainder, it will only do that if you do a `delete(RoleEntity)` by itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried `RoleEntity roleToBeDeleted = roleRepository.findByFileEntityAndName(fileEntity, roleName);
                        roleRepository.delete(roleToBeDeleted);` as well and it doesn't work. I am new to `JPA` so it would be helpful if you could elaborate on how to commit the transaction?

Comment: If you query again right after the delete it will still be there in the 1st level cache. As stated it will only be deleted after the transaction commits. Assuming you use `@Transactional` that will be automatic after the service method executed. You should check the database after the tx commit, not inside the transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have enabled logging SQL queries on the console yet I can't see the delete query at all despite calling `delete()` or `deleteBy..()`. Any idea why so?

Answer (score 0):

Other database query is logged when you call I think service method?
Yot call the jpa delete method.

```
JPA Method roleRepository.findByFileEntityAndName(fileEntity, roleName);
```

return something maybe try show check.

Comment: Actually the issue was that I was calling a wrong method from a persistence service in my code. That method was a `readOnlyTransaction()` which didn't allow me to do the delete so I had to use another method `withTransaction()` that solved my issue.